# return a new list from a list stopped at certain location

Tags: python

I can't get code to make this work for the life of me.

> In this exercise your function will receive one parameter, a list of
>   strings. Your function will make and return a new list that only
>   includes the copies of strings from the parameter up to, but not
>   including the string `kahn`. `kahn` will be in the list.

Expected result:

```
words_up_to_kahn(["kirk", "spock", "luke", "charlie", "kahn", "bob"]) -> ["kirk", "spock", "luke", "charlie"]
words_up_to_kahn(["ernie", "kahn", "bert", "teal'c"]) -> ["ernie"]
```

**Examples:**
Would it be something like this?

```
return words[0:kahn]
```

Or something like this:

```
def words_up_to_kahn(words):
    new = ""
    c = 0
    while words[c] != "kahn":
        new = new + words[c]
        c = c + 1
    return new
```

Or something else?

Comment: `list.index()` might be useful here.

Comment: i added some codes that ive been trying bare with me ive been using python for less then 1 week

Comment: Have you tried the function you've written? It appears it would work (except in the case where "kahn" is the first word). If it works, where's the problem?

Comment: @Evert the problem is that OP concatenates strings from the original list in `new` variable, while the result should be a new list of strings.

Comment: @AudriusKažukauskas Whoops; overlooked the lack of square brackets around new and words. Otherwise it'd work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest solution I believe.

Conditional statements and `.index("kahn")` are your friends:

```python
def up_to_kahn(lst):
    return lst if ("kahn" not in lst) else lst[:lst.index("kahn")]

assert up_to_kahn(["kirk", "spock", "luke", "charlie", "kahn", "bob"]) == \
    ["kirk", "spock", "luke", "charlie"]
assert up_to_kahn(["ernie", "kahn", "bert", "teal'c"]) == ["ernie"]
```

Also this is clearly copy-pasted from a textbook. Please don't use Stack Overflow as a homework-answers site. That said, here's the answer.

Comment: i normally wouldn't I just have a really bad teacher and I learn more of the pros on this site. Its a 40 question homework assignment and that was the only one giving me grief. its stuff we haven't covered yet.

Comment: Honestly, stackoverflow is more useful than any programming class ive ever taken but you should still do your homework (or at least edit the copy-paste lol) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want an alternative approach, for following `itertools` solution is designed to do this:

```
from itertools import takewhile

def words_up_to_kahn(word_list):
    return list(takewhile(lambda x: x != 'kahn', word_list))

print words_up_to_kahn(["kirk", "spock", "luke", "charlie", "kahn", "bob"])
print words_up_to_kahn(["ernie", "kahn", "bert", "teal'c"])
```

Giving:

```
['kirk', 'spock', 'luke', 'charlie']
['ernie']
```